# Reading text files into a python list of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a text file within it there are dictionaries in this format

```
{'name':'Jack', 'age': 20}
{'name': 'Joseph', 'age': 13}
{'name':'anna', 'age': 54}
{'name': "NK", 'age': 0}
```

I now want to read the text file into a list of dictionaries in the format

```
[{'name':'Jack', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'Joseph', 'age': 13}, {'name':'anna', 'age': 54}, 
{'name': "NK", 'age': 0}]
```

So far, i used the below code

```
val_cont_file = open('answers.txt', 'r')
f = val_cont_file.read()
train_answers = f.split("\n")
train_answers = list(filter(None, train_answers))
val_cont_file.close()
```

and the output to this is

```
["{'name':'Jack', 'age': 20}", "{'name': 'Joseph', 'age': 13}", "{'name':'anna', 'age': 
54}", '{\'name\': "NK", \'age\': 0}']
```

which is far from what i would want. How can i produce the desired output, I appreciate for the time and help

Comment: The file looks a lot like JSON, have you tried [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) ?

Comment: The file definitely looks like json but its saved as a ".txt" file format. Using json.loads results to TypeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using `ast` module

**Ex:**

```
import ast

with open('answers.txt', 'r') as infile:
    result = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in infile if line.strip()]
```

Comment: I have tried running this its returning `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`. What could be wrong ?

Comment: Probably because you have an empty new line

Comment: oh yeah thank you @Rakesh i have seen that and fixed it already. But i noticed there are some cases where a dict like `{'name': 'karlson', ' age ': 30}` returns an error due to the whitespaces in the key 'age'. I have a large text file (about 20K) lines. How can i correct this issue?